# Can we migrate a question with an open bounty?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, bounty, migration

This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537751/how-to-find-what-processes-could-spawn-multiple-explorer-exe-processes-on-a-wi is completely off-topic, yet managed to evade closure before the OP put a bounty on it.

It appears to just be a question about Windows processes, not about programming, and should probably be migrated to SU or closed. Since it has a bounty on it, though, it will be another week before anybody can close it.

How do we handle a situation like this?

Comment: Treat it like any other bountied question that needs closing: flag for moderator attention.